# Selecting zones for touch events with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using https://github.com/n33/jquery.touch for creating touch events.
Wanting to use some gestures around all the body but the only map object with id "map".
I'm trying with:

```
$('body').not('#map');
```

and other variations, but these gestures still work in the map.

My code:

```
 var touch = $('#body').not('#map');

 touch.enableTouch({useMouse: true});


 touch.on('doubleTap', function() { gestures("double"); });
```

Comment: It is hard to know what you mean without seeing your markup.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to add an event handler you'd need to do something like:

```
var touch = $('#body'),
    exclude = $('#map');

touch.enableTouch({useMouse: true});


touch.on('doubleTap', function(e) { 
    var $touchedElement = $(e.target);

     if (!$touchedElement.is(exclude) {
         gestures("double");
     }
});
```

Comment: The trouble is that the gestures fine well in all the body. I just want to take off some zones without touch gestures.

Comment: @bullC That's what I assumed. Does this not work for your purposes? If you go to the jsfiddle, clicks are logged on everything except #map.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Your code works great! But look the library I posted. My code is something like this. (I updated my code in the main post).

Comment: @bullC Updated accordingly. I think this should work for you.

Comment: It doesn't work for me mate. I noticed you missed a parenthesis but even correcting that it doesn't work. With that method the gestures are not caught in any area. Anyway thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @bullC It looks like the jquery.touch plugin reports the bound element as the target, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to set this in the selector itself.

```
$('body:not(#map)').touchFunction();
```

Comment: It works fine when I add simple selectors like $('body'). But still works in everyplace when I try to take out some elements of the body in the selector.

Comment: Then you may need to store an array or exempted selectors and in your handler function check if e.target has any of the exempted classes.